# How to cast string into array with only characters in double quotes

Tags: php, arrays, string, explode

I need to cast `$string = ("one","two","three,subthree","four")` into PHP array like.

```
$data[0] => "one",
$data[1] => "two",
$data[2] => "three,subthree",
$data[3] => "four"
```

The issue is that the delimiter in 3rd variable contains comma so explode function is making the string into 5 variables instead of 4.

Comment: preg_match_all is your best bet. see my answer.

Comment: Are your array entries allowed to contain `"`? If so, are they escaped with `\ `?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert the string to JSON string and then decode like this

```
$string = '("one","two","three,subthree","four")';
$string = str_replace(['(', ')'], ['[', ']'], $string);

$array = json_decode($string, true);
print_r($array);
```

Working [**demo**](https://3v4l.org/Rs0EU).

---

## Edit:

If you have possibilities to have brackets [`( or )`] in string, you can trim by brackets [`( or )`] and explode by the delimiter `","`. Example:

```
$string = '("one","two","three,subthree","four")';
$string = trim($string, ' ()');

$array = explode('","', $string);
print_r($array);
```

---

Another way is to use `preg_match_all()` by the patter `~"([^"])+"~`

```
$string = '("one","two","three,subthree","four")';
preg_match_all('~"([^"]+)"~', $string, $array);
print_r($array[0]);
```

**[Regex](https://regex101.com/r/ih4vAq/2) explanation:**

- `"` matches a double quote
- `([^"]+)` capturing group
- `[^"]` any characters except double quote
- `+` one or more occurrence
- `"` matches a double quote

Comment: What would happen if there were brackets in any of the strings?

Comment: I didn't consider the case. Now it is updated with the case. Thanks.

Comment: The above three solutions worked for all my scenerios i tested. Thanks @MH2K9

Answer (score 3):

Here's a shorter version to do that:

```
$string = '("one", "two,three")';

preg_match_all('/"([^"]+)"/', $string, $string);

echo "<pre>";
var_dump($string[1]);
```

Output:

```
array(2) {
 [0]=>
  string(3) "one"
 [1]=>
 string(9) "two,three"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [substr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to remove the first `("` and `")` and then use explode:

```
$string = '("one","two","three,subthree","four")';
$s = substr($string,2,-2); 
// now $s is: one","two","three,subthree","four
print_r(explode('","', $s));
```

Which outputs:

```
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three,subthree
    [3] => four
)
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/i7BUX)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `explode` with `trim`

```
$string = '("one","two","three,subthree","four")';
print_r(explode('","',trim($string,'"()')));
```

Working example : https://3v4l.org/4ZERb

Answer (score 0):

A simple way which does the processing of quotes for you is to use `str_getcsv()` (after removing the start and end brackets)...

```
$string = '("one","two","three,subthree","four")';
$string = substr($string, 1, -1);
print_r(str_getcsv($string));
```

gives

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three,subthree
    [3] => four
)
```

Main thing is that it will also work with...

```
$string = '("one","two","three,subthree","four",5)';
```

and output

```
Array
(
    [0] => one
    [1] => two
    [2] => three,subthree
    [3] => four
    [4] => 5
)
```